# CSS how to align text inside sidebar

Tags: php, html, css, sidebar

Well, I have sidebar but text(in my case tables) inside sidebar are not aligned like I want.
From one .php I call another inside sidebar, like this:

```
<div id="sidebar2"> <?php include("tiket.php");?></div>
```

Here is it CSS of sidebar:

```
#sidebar2 {
    width: 240px;
    float: right;
    padding: 40px;
    background: #264988;
    color: #e1d2c7;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

An this is how it looks:

[image]

How to put text on the left of the sidebar?

Comment: What text do you mean, "Ukloni"? Or the text inside the table?

Comment: It seems you content is too wide to fit in the side-bar, so you would have to fix that first.

Comment: i couldnt determine whats the sidebar for this page from the screenshot you've atached, ccare to point that out? also have you tried using "absolute position" for your sidebar ? although we need more info about your css parent in order to do that

Comment: Well, I mean on whole table. I want to put table on the left. On this picture sidebar is this blue surface (first go gradient blue, the white background and then dark blue sidebar).

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you gave us the complete source code of the sidebar, or told us where it was located.

I think that the reason why the text is not aligned to the left is because you put in `text-align:justify;`. *Remove that line*.

```
#sidebar2 {
    width: 240px;
    float: right;
    padding: 40px;
    background: #264988;
    color: #e1d2c7;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

What `justify` does is *spread the text out evenly*, which can be unhelpful if you don't have much text.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain exactly what you want to do. Give the complete source code for the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest with CSS3

```
#sidebar2 table {
    text-align: left;
}
```

you can read more about it over here
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp